# LINQ collections discrepancy?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question about two bits of code that seem to function the same way at a glance but produce different results when I build and run them.

Code A:

```
    String[] colors = {"green", "red", "blue", "brown"};

    var query = colors.Where(c => c.Contains("e"));

    query = query.Where(c=> c.Contains("n"));

    Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
```

This produces a console output of "1", as presumably the only value left over is "green" (contains both an e and an n).

If the code is subtly altered however, the result is different

Code B:

```
    String[] colors = {"green", "red", "blue", "brown"};

    string s = "e";
    var query = colors.Where(c => c.Contains(s));

    s = "n";
    query = query.Where(c=> c.Contains("n"));

    Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
```

This produces a console output of "2", and the values left over in "query" are "green, brown". As far as I can tell, the reason is because we're assigning s the value of "n" where it previously held "e". If I dump the contents of "query", It will contain "green/brown" despite the fact that I've already pared down query to all values that contain an 'e'.

If anyone could explain why this happens that would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing different results due to "deferred execution". I.e. when you call `Where()`, it doesn't actually *do* anything with your collection. It just returns an `IEnumerable<string>` implementation that *will* do something, once you try to access the enumeration.

So in your second example, where you refer to the variable `s` in your query lambda, by the time the first query is executed, you've changed the variable to the value `"n"`, and so both queries do the same filtering, returning the full count of 2.

Note that if you change the code example so that it looks like this:

```
String[] colors = {"green", "red", "blue", "brown"};

string s = "e";
var query = colors.Where(c => c.Contains(s)).ToArray();

s = "n";
query = query.Where(c=> c.Contains("n"));

Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
```

…it will produce the result you expected. The above calls `ToArray()` which forces evaluation of the enumeration, using the current value of `s` at the time. Later changes to the variable will then not affect the final result.

Answer (score 1):

In the second snippet, you're creating a closure around the variable s. The expression in the where clause isn't evaluated until you enumerate the list with .Count(). At that point, s has already been re-assigned so your where query is actually colors.Where(c => c.Contains("n")).Where(c => c.Contains("n"))

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that LINQ queries are based on 'deferred execution' - the query is built but not really executed unless you specifically iterate over the collection (foreach loop for example) or call .ToList() or .ToArray() extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your `where` logic will actually be executed, when the `Count()` call occurs. So, before the `Console.WriteLine`, your lambda expressions have not been executed even once (causing your string variable to evaluate to `n` in the lambdas later on, as the assignment has already been performed - you can check that with your debugger). This concept is called [Deferred Execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx) and quite useful when querying databases (as the SQL is compiled and run against the database when the whole query is known).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right it is because of the `s = "n";`
Linq is lazy evaluated. Here in your example the first `where` is not evaluated directly. Only when it is needed (iterated over). And because the where lambdas have captured the `s` variable, the current value is used even for the first lambda.
Try a `ToList()` before the second `where` to force evaluation of the first IEnumerable.

```
String[] colors = { "green", "red", "blue", "brown" };
string s = "e";
var query = colors.Where(c => c.Contains(s)).ToList();

s = "n";
query = query.Where(c => c.Contains("n"));
```